# How much further culture does a civic cost?

Tags: civilization-6

Civilization 6. I invested a lot of culture to a specific civic, and I'm just two turns away from getting it.

For strategic reasons, I'm willing to trade at a loss for Relics, if and only if  they'll increase my culture output enough for me to get that civic in one turn instead of two .

I can get a feel of approximately how much culture is still missing from the round progress bar, but I'm unsure whether or not a little more culture would tip me over to getting it next turn.

I know my exact culture output by turn.

Mousing over in the civics tree, I can see the *total* culture cost of that specific civic, but not the *remaining* cost to be paid in addition to what was already paid.

**Is there a way to view the precise remaining culture cost that needs to be paid to get a civic?**

My backup plan is to save, do the trades, and load back if it fails. But I hate to do that.

Comment: The answer to your question requires more than you're telling. (1) what is your current culture per turn? (2) Do you have any racial benefits to culture output? (3) Do you have Pingala (with culture buffs) in the city where you'd place the relic? (4) Any monuments which increase the value?

Comment: As your question currently stands, you would need to **double** your culture output in order to **halve** your turn count. That's the simple math.

Comment: @Flater My culture output is 14 point something per turn.  As I understand it,  a +4 increase could be enough to half the number of turns from 2 to 1 turns,  or not,  depending on the exact number of missing for cost for the civic.  If it is,  e.g., 16, then 14 is not enough but 14+4 is enough.

Comment: @Flater I fail to see the relevance,  but I'm playing with Kenya,  and don't have any culture buffs.

Comment: The buffs are revelant because you're comparing 14 (post-buff) to 4 (pre-buff). Any buff is going to increase the +4 gain, which can swing in your favor.

Comment: Another way to increase your culture is to switch the focus of your cities towards it

Comment: "Is there a way to view the precise remaining culture cost that needs to be paid to get a civic?"  The specific question remains unanswered, although it is really part of the broader question of how much culture the player would need to add and the still broader question of how to tell whether/when certain actions (e.g., trade artifact at low price) would suffice.

Comment: I'm also curious about remaining Science for a Technology.  I've only tried a few UI and no Civic and/or Technology mods but I've yet to see a description that is promising.